# How to set request encoding in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, character-encoding

I have a problem in my Java webapp.

Here is the code in index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q"/>
        </form>

        Res: <%= request.getParameter("q") %>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I wireshark a request, my browser sends this header:

```
GET /kjd/index.jsp?q=%C3%A9 HTTP/1.1\r\n
...
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*\r\n
```

And the Tomcat server returns me this:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n
```

But if I send "é"(%C3%A9 in UTF-8) in my form, "Ã©" is displayed instead.

What I understand is that the browser sends an "é" encoded with UTF-8 (the %C3%A9).

But the server interpret this as ISO-8859-1. So the %C3 is decoded as Ã and %A9 as ©, and then sends back the response encoded in UTF-8.

In the code, the requests should be decoded with UTF-8:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But, if I send this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/kjd/index.jsp?q=%E9
```

the "%E9" is decocded with ISO-8859-1 and an "é" is displayed.

Why isn't this working? Why requests are decoded with ISO-8859-1?

I've tried it on Tomcat 6 and 7, and on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: [This apache wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) may help you; run through it to see if there are any changes you can make.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` only sets the encoding of the request **body** (which is been used by POST requests), not the encoding of the request **URI** (which is been used by GET requests).

You need to set the `URIEncoding` attribute to `UTF-8` in the `<Connector>` element of Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml` to get Tomcat to parse the request URI (and the query string) as UTF-8. This indeed defaults to ISO-8859-1. See also the [Tomcat HTTP Connector Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

or to ensure that the URI is parsed using the same encoding as the body<sup>1</sup>:

```xml
<Connector ... useBodyEncodingForURI="true">
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [JSP/Servlet request](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest)

---

<sup>1</sup> From [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) (emphasis mine):

> This setting is present **for compatibility with Tomcat 4.1.x**, where the
>   encoding specified in the contentType, or explicitly set using
>   Request.setCharacterEncoding method was also used for the parameters
>   from the URL. The default value is false.

---

Please get rid of those *scriptlets* in your JSP. The  `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` is called at the wrong moment. It would be too late whenever you've properly used a Servlet to process the request. You'd rather like to use a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this. The  `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` part is already implicitly done by `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` in top of JSP.

I also [strongly recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to replace the old fashioned `<%= request.getParameter("q") %>` *scriptlet* by [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) `${param.q}`, or with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) XML escaping `${fn:escapeXml(param.q)}` to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Note that not all browsers happily send UTF-8 query parameters, looking at you IE : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/04/22/unicode-in-url-changes-for-ie11/

Answer (score 11):

you just need to uncomment below portion of code in conf/web.xml (**Tomcat server** `web.xml`) that filter all request and convert into UTF-8.

```
 <!-- A filter that sets character encoding that is used to decode -->
 <!-- parameters in a POST request -->
 <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
 </filter>

  <!-- The mapping for the Set Character Encoding Filter -->
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

that's it. work fine in tomcat