# request/response parameters are encoded by browser by default?

Tags: java, html, encoding, webserver, http-request

when i send the request to webserver, as per my understanding , browsers does not encode the request
 paramtersfor example :- some value entered by user under textarea (be it post or get form submission) by default. 
 Similarly webservers(specially tomcat) does not do that. Is my understanding correct?

i am aware browser/webserver do the encoding/decoding foe url by  default but not sure about request paramters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `URL encoding` on servers you need to configure in the application server, here is the link [Configuring URL Encoding on Tomcat](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+URL+Encoding+on+Tomcat+Application+Server)

Comment: what about request paramters/attributes?Are they encoded by default?

Comment: @emilly Here is a similar issue that may be helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876697/how-to-set-request-encoding-in-tomcat)

Comment: @emilly here is the [description](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)