# CharacterEncodingFilter does not decode @RequestParam variables

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My Spring MVC REST endpoint contains a number of GET request parameters, as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> myLookup(@RequestParam(value = "securityType"))
```

I'm using a `UriComponentsBuilder` to build the request which correctly encodes any `+` values as `%2B`

I've also set a `CharacterEncodingFilter` as the first filter in my `web.xml` and set `encoding` to `"UTF-8`" and `forceEncoding` to `true`

However, when I log my `securityType` parameter above it still includes the `%2B`

Obviously I can manually decode this myself, but I'm wondering what am I missing here, or is there a better way to do things?

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876697/how-to-set-request-encoding-in-tomcat

Comment: Looks good, I will close the question, thanks