# What is the point of Tomcat's setting URIEncoding?

Tags: tomcat, encoding, uri, uriencoding, iri

In Apache Tomcat, parameter `URIEncoding` tells Tomcat how to interpret incoming URIs:

> URIEncoding
>
> This specifies the character encoding used to decode the URI bytes,
>   after %xx decoding the URL. If not specified, ISO-8859-1 will be used.

*[Apache Tomcat 7 - The HTTP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)*

However, as explained for example in [What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters) , non-ASCII characters in URIs are always encoded in UTF-8, following current standards (RFC 3986 and 3987).

So:

- Why is there even a setting for something that is mandated by a standard?
- Why is the default different from what the standard mandates? (ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8)

Is this simply because the Tomcat setting predates the standard, and was retained for backwards compatibility? Or is there some situation where a value different from UTF-8 makes sense?

Comment: Related question: [How to set request encoding in Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876697/how-to-set-request-encoding-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of parameter `URIEncoding` in Tomcat 8 - [Apache Tomcat 8 - The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html):

> This specifies the character encoding used to decode the URI bytes, after %xx decoding the URL. If not specified, UTF-8 will be used unless the org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE system property is set to true in which case ISO-8859-1 will be used.

Thus the description was changed from that of Apache Tomcat 7. The default value of `org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE` is false from Apache Tomcat 8. So UTF-8 is the default value of URIEncoding for Apache Tomcat 8, which means that Tomcat now follows the standard (and common usage).

---

As to why Tomcat used ISO 8859-1 as the default URI encoding until Tomcat 7:

That seems to be because the Tomcat devevelopers believed this to be what the Servlet specification requires (as the name of the setting STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE indicates).

As a matter of fact, the Servlet spec does not explicitly mention URI encoding in any version. It does, however, mention that POST data must be parsed as ISO 8859-1 if the `Content-Type` HTTP header does not specify an encoding via `charset` (Servlet Specification V2.5, "Request data encoding"). Apparently this was interpreted to mean that query parameters (and thus the whole URI) should also be decoded as ISO 8859-1 by default.

The root problem is arguably that the Servlet Specification does not specify the default encoding to use for decoding URIs, let alone a way to change this encoding. This in turn is probably because the URI spec originally did not allow for non-ASCII characters in URIs - this was only standardized by introducing IRIs, see [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) from January 2005. Therefore every servlet container had to come up with their own default value and configuration parameter, such as `URIEncoding` in Apache Tomcat.

These two problems have been reported as bugs against the Servlet Specification:

- [SERVLET_SPEC-145](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/servlet-api/issues/145) ([original, broken link](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-145)) - Specify default URL encoding
- [SERVLET_SPEC-146](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/servlet-api/issues/146) ([original, broken link](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-146)) - Add ability to specify URL encoding

Maybe the Servlet specification will be amended one day... . At least SERVLET_SPEC-146 is now marked resolved.

Comment: Interesting doc find, thanks. I should really read the docs sometimes :-). So it seems the Apache Devs believe that the Servlet specs requires decoding URIs as ISO 8859-1. In fact, I have not found _anything_ about URI encoding in the servlet spec (3.0), and there is an open issue (https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-146 ) about this. So it looks like it was never properly specified... . Do you mind if I edit this into your answer?

Comment: Also see https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-145 . Seems the Servlet spec is ambiguous on what the URI encoding default is.

Comment: Answer expanded with my own research. Feel free to re-edit if you spot any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I see that at least for Tomcat 6 and below URIEncoding was not only important, but necessary, with many people having issues if not explicitly setting it to 'UTF-8'. As for your question, I can only assume that it is for backward compatibility. Developers hate to remove code once they have written it, even if the possibility of ever needing it again is zero :)