# Unable to read Japanese characters from jsp through request while inserting in Database

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to insert Japanese character in oracle database, for that I have changed column datatype as NVARCHAR2 and following changes are done in jsp file.

```
<%a page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
```

followed by changing url encoding in apache server.XML and set it to utf-8.

In action class I wrote `(request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");)`.

But when I retrieve customer comments written in Japanese with help of request parameter it gives me characters like `" å¯©æ»æé ";`.

Please let me know what additional changes need to be done so that java can read Japanese characters.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text in a code block

Comment: If you use Tomcat, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6876740/3511123 (if you use a different servlet engine, see its documentation).