# JSP not showing correct UTF-8 contents for HTML form POST

Tags: java, forms, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Java 11 with Tomcat 9 with the latest JSP/JSTL. I'm testing in Chrome 71 and Firefox 64.0 on Windows 10. I have the following test document:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <c:if test="${not empty param.fullName}">
    <p>Hello, ${param.fullName}.</p>
  </c:if>

  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Full name: <input name="fullName" /></label>
    </div>
    <button>Say Hello</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is perhaps the simplest form possible. As you know the form `method` defaults to `get`, the form `action` defaults to `""` (submitting to the same page), and the form `enctype` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If I enter the name "Flávio José" (a famous Brazilian forró singer and musícian) in the field and submit, the form is submitted via HTTP `GET` to the same page using `hello.jsp?fullName=Fl%C3%A1vio+Jos%C3%A9`. This is correct, and the page says:

```
Hello, Flávio José.
```

If I change the form `method` to `post` and enter the same name "Flávio José", the form contents are instead submitted via `POST`, with HTTP request contents:

```
fullName=Fl%C3%A1vio+Jos%C3%A9
```

This also appears correct. But this time the page says:

```
Hello, FlÃ¡vio JosÃ©.
```

Rather than seeing `%C3%A` as a sequence of UTF-8 octects, JSP seems to think that these are a series of ISO-8859-1 octets (or code page 1252 octets), and is therefore decoding them to the wrong character sequence.

But where is it getting ISO-8859-1? What is my JSP page lacking to indicate the correct encoding?

I'll note also that [WHATWG specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing) says that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` octets should be parsed as UTF-8 by default. Is the Java servlet specification simply broken? How do I work around this?

Comment: Does the Content-Type of the HTTP request specify a charset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by Tomcat, but the root problem is the Java Servlet 4 specification, which is incorrect and outdated.

Originally HTML 4.0.1 said that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded octets should be [decoded as US-ASCII](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). The servlet specification changed this to say that, if the request encoding is not specified, the octets should be decoded as ISO-8859-1. Tomcat is simply following the servlet specification.

There are two problems with the Java servlet specification. The first is that the modern interpretation of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is that encoded octets [should be decoded using UTF-8](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing). The second problem is that tying the octet decoding to the resource charset confuses two levels of decoding.

Take another look at this `POST` content:

```
fullName=Fl%C3%A1vio+Jos%C3%A9
```

You'll notice that it is ASCII!! It doesn't matter if you consider the `POST` HTTP request charset to be `ISO-8859-1`, `UTF-8`, or `US-ASCII`—you'll still wind up with exactly the same Unicode characters *before* decoding the octets! What encoding is used to decode the encoding octets is completely separate.

As a further example, let's say I download a text file `instructions.txt` that is clearly marked as ISO-8859-1, and it contains the URI `https://example.com/example.jsp?fullName=Fl%C3%A1vio+Jos%C3%A9`. Just because the text file has a charset of `ISO-8859-1`, does that mean I need to decode `%C3%A` using ISO-8859-1? Of course not! The charset used for decoding URI characters *is a separate level of decoding on top of the resource content type charset*! Similarly the octets of values encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should be decoded using UTF-8, regardless of the underlying charset of the resource.

There are several workarounds, some of them found at found by looking at the [Tomcat character encoding FAQ to "use UTF-8 everywhere"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/liklBg#CharacterEncoding-Q8).

**Set the request character encoding in your `web.xml` file.**

Add the following to your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file:

```
<request-character-encoding>UTF-8</request-character-encoding>
```

This setting is agnostic of the servlet container implementation, and is defined forth in the servlet specification. (You should be able to alternatively put it in Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` file, if want a global setting and don't mind changing the Tomcat configuration.)

**Set the `SetCharacterEncodingFilter` in your `web.xml` file.**

Tomcat has a proprietary equivalent: use the `org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter` in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, as the Tomcat FAQ above mentions, and as illustrated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833977/421049, excerpted below:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will make your web application only work on Tomcat, so it's better to put this in the Tomcat installation `conf/web.xml` file instead, as the post above mentions. In fact Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` installations have these two sections, but commented out; simply uncomment them and things should work.

**Force the request character encoding to UTF-8 in the JSP or servlet.**

You can force the character encoding of the servlet request to UTF-8, somewhere early in the JSP:

```
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

But that is ugly, unwieldy, error-prone, and goes against modern best practices—JSP scriptlets shouldn't be used anymore.

Hopefully we can get a newer Java servlet specification to remove any relationship between the resource charset and the decoding of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` octets, and simply state that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` octets must be decoded as UTF-8, as is modern practice as clarified by the latest W3C and WHATWG specifications.

*Update:* I've updated the Tomcat FAQ on [Character Encoding Issues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/liklBg#CharacterEncoding-Q3) with this information.

Comment: Note that `<request-character-encoding>` and `<response-character-encoding>` are new options from the [Servlet API 4.0 spec (see page A-204)](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf).